# Select2 ajax/custom query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I have this code:

```
     var locations = [
        <?php foreach($locations as $loc) {echo '{ id: ' . $loc['id'] . ', text: "' . $loc['name'] . '" },';} ?>
   ];
    $("#location-id").select2({
        data: locations,
        placeholder: '<?= lang("hol") ?>?',
        allowClear: true,
        minimumInputLength: 3,
    });
```

but the locations array is really big, nearly 10000 elements and the browser freezes for some seconds when loading it especially when I have more select box like this, so I think I need some custom query or ajax function to not to load the whole array into select2. What I found on the internet is outdated and not working with select2 4.0.3. On the select2' homepage, there is an example code with ajax which is I think do what I need but with remote data:

```
$(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
  ajax: {
    url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
      return {
        q: params.term, // search term
        page: params.page
      };
    },
    processResults: function (data, params) {
      // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
      // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
      // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
      // scrolling can be used
      params.page = params.page || 1;

      return {
        results: data.items,
        pagination: {
          more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
        }
      };
    },
    cache: true
  },
  escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
  minimumInputLength: 1,
  templateResult: formatRepo, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
  templateSelection: formatRepoSelection // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
});
```

but I need to do it with local data.

Can someone help me to not let the select2 load the entire array?

Thanks

Comment: Don't preload your array but create an endpoint on your server that serves the array paginated. The example in the website https://select2.github.io/examples.html is not outdated.

Comment: what i found on stack overflow was outdated, and how can i do that? i dont need them paginated i need them for searching. i need al the results when the user type 3 chars for that 3 chars